# Kendo Grid EditorTemplateName DropDownList Id Not Posting

Tags: drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, mvc-editor-templates

I have a simple kendo grid that I am trying to associate an editor template with. The foreign key is the only property that is sent down to the client so I can't give the editor template a model type of the foreign key property.

**Configuration for Kendo Grid**

```
    protected override void Configure(GridBuilder<AreaModel> grid)
    {
        grid.Columns(c =>
        {
            c.Bound(a => a.Description);
            c.Bound(p => p.CompanyId).ClientTemplate("#= CompanyDescription#").EditorTemplateName("DropDown/CompanyId").Width(160);
            c.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(200);
            c.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(110);
        });
        grid.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("New Area"));
        grid.Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine));
        grid.DataSource(d => d
            .Ajax()
            .Model(m => m.Id(p => p.Id))
            .Create("GridInsert", "Area")
            .Update("GridUpdate", "Area")
            .Destroy("GridDelete", "Area"));
    }
}
```

The editor template is straight forward as well. Everything works except that the value is not posted to the server.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("CompanyId")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataSource(d => d.Read("CompaniesData", "Company")))
```

Can anybody help me out on this one?

Answer (score 0):

`modelview` propoerty name which should maintain dropdownlist's selected value must be the Name of dropdownlist in editorTemplate and the type of `datavaluefield` and property should be same.